# File upload and resize asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am trying to create a gallery where the user uploads an image using fileupload control then it is resized then saved to the file system on the server. They can upload jpg, png and gif files.

I know the procedure where you can upload then check the size but this seems inefficient.
I heard about memorystream but unsure how to use it.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You can't resize the picture until the full file is on the server side.

Yes it is inefficient, but it's the reality of the web. The only alternative is to use client side code (activex, silverlight, flash), but it's probably not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code - The size specified is in kilobytes. The default is 4096 KB (4 MB).

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength < yourSize) //Adjust your size 
{
   .........
}
else
{
Label1.Text = "File size exceeds maximum limit 20 MB.";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the max upload will be 4mb (using .Net) - it can be reset using

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="sss" maxRequestLength="xxxx" />
```

However, this is really nasty way to do it as friendly error messages rarely gets picked up (i.e. no nice messages). Even using ContentLength on the Upload will be blown if HTTPRunTime is exceeded as well. Microsoft sugests using a larger httRuntime value and then restricting through ContentLength (breaking both will result in the nasty error - usually).

Another option is to use something like this ==> [Ajax Uploader](http://ajaxuploader.com/Demo/Large-File-Upload.aspx)